Group permissions for writing on a system
I've gone through quite a few posts on this, and I feel I must be doing something quite basic wrong.
I have a system that has mounted an NFS drive. On there, there is a folder owned by a user, PGCseismolab. This user belongs to a primary group called "seismic".
On that same system is another user called "sysop". That user "sysop" has to belong to its own primary group, "sysop", but is a member of other groups too.

$ groups PGCseismolab
PGCseismolab : seismic sudo users
$ groups sysop
sysop : sysop adm audio users seismic admin

I have folders FolderA and FolderB that I want to be owned by PGCseismolab, but be read and writeable to anyone in the group seismic. Here is what that folder looks like:

$ ls -la /path/to/nfs/mount/folder/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 PGCseismolab users   4096 May  1 22:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root         root    4096 Jan 25 11:38 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 PGCseismolab seismic 4096 May  1 21:52 FolderA
drwxrwsr-x  2 PGCseismolab seismic 4096 May  1 22:24 FolderB

If I try to create a file inside FolderB as user sysop, I get a permission error.

$ touch /path/to/nfs/mount/folder/FolderB/testfile
touch: cannot touch '/path/to/nfs/mount/folder/FolderB/testfile': Permission denied

I have done a similar test on the local file system, and it works ok.
Is this an issue because the folders reside on filesystem on a different computer mounted via NFS?
I'll note that if I set the primary group of sysop to be seismic, then it works on the NFS mountpoint. But I need to have the primary group for the user sysop to remain as sysop. My other option is to make the folder writeable to everyone, but I would prefer not to.
Thanks!
